# Como posicionar adecuadamente mi footer?

Tags: css, flexbox

Estoy tratando que mi pie de página quede de este modo:
[image: pie de pagina]

Como podría posicionar correctamente mis elementos? de forma que se adapten a la página si la estiro o la acorto??

adjunto tambien el main de mi página pero este ya lo tengo correctamente configurado, es solo para dar un referencia y cuerpo a la pregunta.

```css
main {
    position: relative;
    margin-top: 6px;
    height: 120%;
    top: 10rem;
    bottom: 5rem;
    height: 100%;
    overflow-y: auto;
}


footer {
    background-color: #ff6600;
    color: #ffffff;
    padding: 12px;
    height: 4rem;
    text-align: center;
    position: fixed;
    left: 0px;
    right: 0px;
    bottom: 0px;
    z-index: 0;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
}

footer a img#logotipo {
    width: auto;
    height: 3rem;
    border: 2px solid black;
    flex: 1;
    align-self: flex-start;
    
}

footer a#up {
    padding-left: 0.6rem;
    padding-right: 1rem;
    background-color: #9e9e9e;
    border-color: #00bcd4 1px solid;
    border-radius: 4px;
    height: 3rem;
    width: 3rem;
    font-size: 3em;
    text-align: center;
    color: #ffffff;
    border: 2px solid black;
}

footer small#date {
    border: 2px solid black;
    flex: 1;
    align-self: flex-end;
}

footer small#empresa {
    font-size: 10px;
    border: 2px solid black;
    flex: 1;
    align-self: flex-end;
}
```

```html
<html>
<head>
<head>
<body>
<main>
<p>contenido de la web</p>
</main>
<footer>
        <a href="#" alt="up" id="up">^</a>
        <a href="index.html" alt="main"><img src="https://logos.flamingtext.com/Word-Logos/prueba-design-sketch-name.png" alt="logotipo" id="logotipo"></a>
        <small id="date">2021</small>
        <small id="empresa">Empresa</small>
</footer>
<body>
<html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Podrías usar *flex*

De manera que tenemos tres elementos `.flexSection`

Al ser tres secciones en el footer, cada uno tiene `33%` de `width` (queda `99%`, aproximado a `100%`)

Para que se aplique el `width` y a la vez se vea como `inline`, le aplicamos `inline-block`

Podemos obtener cada elemento con `.nth-child`, es decir, el elemento "n"

```
selector:nth-child(1)
```

De esta manera puedes obtener algún elemento específico con un selector específico

[Referencia](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/CSS/:nth-child)

Al segundo `.flexSection`, vamos a usar el [selector de hijo](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/CSS/Child_combinator) para obtener un nodo (el elemento `<a>` dentro de este) y darle `display:block` para que se tome en cuenta como un párrafo y el `<small>` se salte a la otra línea

Finalmente, al tercero usamos el mismo selector de hijos, le damos una posición relativa al `<small>` para que podamos acomodarlo con `bottom`, con la propiedad `bottom` la ubicamos hacia abajo

```css
main {
    position: relative;
    margin-top: 6px;
    height: 120%;
    top: 10rem;
    bottom: 5rem;
    height: 100%;
    overflow-y: auto;
}


footer {
    background-color: #ff6600;
    color: #ffffff;
    padding: 12px;
    height: 4rem;
    text-align: center;
    position: fixed;
    left: 0px;
    right: 0px;
    bottom: 0px;
    z-index: 0;
    display: flex;
}

footer a img#logotipo {
    width: auto;
    height: 3rem;
    flex: 1;
    align-self: flex-start;
    
}

footer a#up {
    padding-left: 0.6rem;
    padding-right: 1rem;
    background-color: #9e9e9e;
    height: 3rem;
    width: 3rem;
    font-size: 3em;
    text-align: center;
    color: #ffffff;
}

footer small#date {
    flex: 1;
    align-self: flex-end;
}

footer small#empresa {
    font-size: 10px;
    flex: 1;
    align-self: flex-end;
}

.flexSection {
  width:33%;
}

.flexSection:nth-child(1) {
  display:inline-block;
  text-align:left;
}

.flexSection:nth-child(2) > a {
  display:block;
}

.flexSection:nth-child(3) {
  display:inline-block;
  text-align:right;
}

.flexSection:nth-child(3) > small {
  display:inline-block;
  position:relative;
  bottom:-75%;
}
```

```html
<html>
<head>
<head>
<body>
<main>
<p>contenido de la web</p>
</main>
<footer>
  <div class="flexSection">
        <a href="#" alt="up" id="up">^</a>
  </div>
  <div class="flexSection">
        <a href="index.html" alt="main"><img src="https://logos.flamingtext.com/Word-Logos/prueba-design-sketch-name.png" alt="logotipo" id="logotipo"></a>
        <small id="date">2021</small>
  </div>
  <div class="flexSection">
        <small id="empresa">Empresa</small>
  </div>
</footer>
<body>
<html>
```

Comment: si quisiera subir el año un poco más arriba como sería? he probado lo que me has dicho y va perfecto!!! pero por alguna razón el año me sale escondido debajo de la web. He probado usando top para subirlo pero no hace nada creo que choca con el logotipo

Comment: @WinterIsBack La propiedad `top` no funcionará si no hay una posición relativa, prueba poniéndole `position:relative` al año y luego con `top`

Comment: mm he probado pero no funciona correctamente, es como que sigue chocando con la caja del logotipo

Comment: @WinterIsBack [por favor, entra a esta sala de chat para debatir el problema](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/119977/anythingg)